# Синтаксис при формировании массива. ответ сервера 500

Tags: php, сервер

Здравствуйте. Сижу 5й день (не считая выходных) с траблой. Сделал на пхп что-то типо модуля вип-объявлений на сайт.
Модуль работает (сначала был ротатор на jquery, затем опустился до рандомного вывода 1го объявления) с включенным модулем сайт отображается исправно НО! ответ сервера приходит не 200, а 500 О_о Пришел к выводу что что-то по-незнанию накосячил. Исправте пожалуйста, на то как должно быть правильно.

```
$db = mysql_connect("","",""); //проверка имени и пароля и соединение с базой данных
mysql_select_db("",$db); //выборка определенной базы данных
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(text, 200) as text, img, contact, sort, what FROM vips order by rand() limit 1",$db); // выборка с базы данных из таблицы table
if(!$result) // если нет результата выбовки
{
echo "<p>Запрос выборки из базы данных не прошел. Напишите, об этом администрацию: mail@life-prog.ru. <br>Код ошибки:</p>";
exit(mysql_error()); //печатание кода ошибки
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) //если выборка произошла
{

$array = mysql_fetch_array($result); //перекидываем выборку в массив

do
{
echo "<li onclick=\"facechange('.blya');$('#pikame').PikaChoose({startOn:".$array['sort'].", autoPlay:false, showCaption:true});hider1('.hiderrr'); return false;\">
<div class=ttop valign=bottom></div>
<img border=0 align=left hspace=13 src=".$array['img']." width=100>
<h3 class=radv>".$array['what']."</h3>
<p>".$array['text']."</p><br>
<div class=bott><span class=contactt valign=bottom>".$array['contact']."</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</li>";
}
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));
exit(); 
}
else {echo "Информация не может быть извлечена. В таблице нет записей";
exit(); //остановка вывода в браузер
}
?>
```

---

**UPD.**

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# Кэширование на стороне браузера (отдаем нормальные заголовки)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Включаем
ExpiresActive On

# Кэшировать браузером все файлы в течении двух недель (в секундах).
ExpiresDefault A1209600

# Не кэшировать файлы, имеющие тип
ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: показали бы .htaccess ..

Answer (score 1):

Скопировал себе этот код, поправил под свою таблицу, HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

Можно сказать только одно, код корявый. Не понятно для чего столько exit. И зачем вы используете цикл ? Если в запросе получаете только одну строчку данных и судя по вашему комментарию выводите тоже только одну.

Я думаю, что если в ответах приходит ошибка 500, то скорей всего ошибка в настройке apache/php.

Comment: кстати посмотрел лог ошибок апаче... ничего нету.

Answer (score 0):

надо бы посмотреть логи Apache (если он стоит) - там все отображается: ответ 500, причина - такая-то

**UPD:** если ответ 500 - это ВНУТРЕННЯЯ ошибка сервера, а не ошибка программирования.

Comment: FoxManiac, спасибо за совет!
Насчет apache не знаю даже. У меня выделенный сервер под сайт.
Эта внутренняя ошибка возникает только при этом включенном коде. Мне кажет, в php.ini или еще где-то стоит ограничение. Хотелось бы упростить код, может он как-то зацикливается даже не знаю =(, чтобы подстроиться работало с нынешними настройками...
как-то так

Comment: Попробуйте следующее (как я делаю в подобных случаях): комментируйте логические блоки кода поочередно. На чем страничка "отомрет" - то и "зло" :)) Бритва Окама типа :)

Comment: ок пробую, спасибо. Наверняка дела в cakephp :/

Answer (score 0):

В начале пропущено "<?", если, конечно, Вы не пропустили случайно при копировании кода сюда.

Попробуйте закомменитровать exit(); интерпритатор должен вывести  свою ошибку и указать конкретно где была ошибка.

Comment: если бы пропустил, то это бы вышло, как HTML, но не как ошибка 500... вроде...

Comment: Спасибо. Пропустил специально, чтобы код на сайте отображался корректно. exit(); раньше даже не было, я его сам дописал, думал поможет, но ничего не вышло... щас попробую на всякий случай

Comment: http://www.pageranker.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=169:-500-internal-server-error&catid=39:support&Itemid=70

Тут есть возможные варианты ошибок. Тоже как вариант.

Comment: =) я имел ввиду этот сайт.